# Show loading image when video buffer next frames

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video

I' using `html5 video`. I need to show the loading image when video buffering next frame like a `youtube` when video is stop and downloading next frames `youtube` show a loading image which is circle gif image and when video download enough frame to start it loading image disappear.

I'm not asking about first time video start.
I know I can use `poster` while video is not starting or I can use event `loadstart` and `canplay`.

These things work fine when video is starting first time. But problem is that I want loading image when video is stop while playing due to buffering next frame.

So, what I event use or how can I do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you may want to listen to the corresponding events from the video element. A list of available events can be found at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

The two events of interest for your goal are *stalled* and *waiting*, once they are fired you can display your loading animation.